# Filter file by row values

Tags: linux, awk, files, regular-expression

I need to select the rows containing a certain character in the 1st column and having the digits in the 1st column greater than a specific value.

Specifically, I need to select the rows containing a 'G' in 1st column and having the **digits** greater than **50** as shown below:

Input file:

```
764M    qa11279_TPK0002730_50901083/
762M    qa10589_TPK0002730_50796634/
11G     qa17805_TPK0001664_51330191/
56G     qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140G    qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```

Output file:

```
56G     qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140G    qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```

Comment: Where is the output coming from? Maybe there is better option....

Comment: let me guess. `du`  utility. That's what it looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```bsh
$ awk -F' ' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]*G/ { sub(/G/, "", $1); if(+$1 > 50) print }' file 
56 qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140 qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```

Comment: you could do `awk '/^[0-9]*G/ && $1>50'`, since the first column started with digits, then when awk do numeric comparison it converts string to number, so `###xxx` converts to `###` (removing trailing string of characters) and comparing with right-side number (`50` here).

Comment: `-F' '` is doing nothing useful since `' '` is already the default setting for `FS`

Answer (score 2):

Since "G" only ever appears in the first column as shown in your sample input:

```
$ awk '/G/ && ($1+0 > 50)' file
56G     qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140G    qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```

but if it could occur in other fields:

```
$ awk '($1 ~ /G/) && ($1+0 > 50)' file
56G     qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140G    qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @αғsнιη's comment, but fixing the comparison:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+/ && $1 ~ /G$/ && $1+0 > 50' file
56G   qa15384_TPK0001664_51232746/
140G  qa29996_TPK0000949_51951816/
```